# make cloud based application faster and accessible across the globe

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-server

I have been working on cloud based applications. These applications include, web-based portal for merchants to place new orders and REST APIs for them to integrate to their platforms.

These applications are currently hosted on AWS cloud, in Singapore region.

But a few of our customers (based out of Thailand and Vietnam) have complains that they intermittently feel our application is slow.

Also recently one of our customers based out of China reported that he was unable to call our APIs nor access our web-based applications.

How can I make optimisation on an existing cloud based application to service customers across the globe to make it faster and accessible.

Our solution is to deploy application at different regions and expose different end points to different customers.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like an exam question where the answer is "Use AWS CloudFront". However, putting resources in another region may be required depending on exactly what your application does. You should use webpagetest.org to see what is making your application slow from the opposite side of the world from your server, maybe you can optimise the application enough that CloudFront is sufficient instead of additional regions.

Comment: Cloudfront may solve speed problem but what about access problem in China as cloudfront as no servers in China

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an exam question where the answer is "Use AWS CloudFront". However, putting resources in another region may be required depending on exactly what your application does.

**Cloudfront**

CloudFront optimises the delivery of both static and dynamic content. It provides more speed-up for static content as it's effectively delivered from a server near the user. Dynamic content benefits as connections are held open and the network is optimised, which is helpful but not always a huge change.

**Diagnostics Testing**

You should use webpagetest.org to see what is making your application slow from the opposite side of the world from your server, maybe you can optimise the application enough that CloudFront provides sufficient speedup instead of additional regions.

**Problems you might find / should look at**

- Static resources not cached (easy to fix with caching headers)
- High latency (investigate routing, shouldn't be that high)
- Slow processing of requests (optimise application)

**China**

If China continues to be slow after you optimise your application (which may solve the problem) your best option is probably to keep resources deployed there.

**Following Up**

Once you've done diagnostics, if you have trouble working out the problem please start a new question with detailed information and we can help work it out.